# PHP Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, wordpress, logging, implode

i'm getting this warning in apache logs each time i visit my wordpress site:

> [error] [client myiphere] PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/mysitepath/wp-content/themes/mytheme/noscript/views/list-view.php on line 16, referer: http://www.example.com/

Here is a part of list-view.php:

```
<?php
$mytheme = mytheme::getInstance();
$currentContentLayout = $mytheme->WPData['currentContentLayout'];
$contentLayout = $mytheme->settings->contentLayouts->{$currentContentLayout};
$headerClasses = array();
if('no' == $contentLayout->metaPosition){
    $headerClasses = 'no-meta';
} else {
    $headerClasses[] = 'meta-' . $contentLayout->metaPosition;
}
?>
<div class="mytheme-list-view row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <?php while(have_posts()){ the_post();?>
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID();?>" <?php post_class();?> data-mytheme-post-from-id="<?php the_ID();?>">
            <header class="entry-header <?php echo implode(' ', $headerClasses);?>">
...
...
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
$headerClasses = 'no-meta';
```

To this:

```
$headerClasses[] = 'no-meta';
```

The problem occurs when `$headerClasses` is a string, as `implode()` takes an array as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

`implode` function requires `array` as parameter while in if condition you are passing simple string . You shuld use like this

```
if('no' == $contentLayout->metaPosition){
    $headerClasses[] = 'no-meta';              // this should be pass into array
} else {
    $headerClasses[] = 'meta-' . $contentLayout->metaPosition;
}
```

second one . you can check on impload like this

```
<?php echo is_array($headerClasses)? implode(' ', $headerClasses):$headerClasses;?>
```

Comment: I think you need to pass `$headerClasses` into `is_array()`...so it becomes  `<?php echo is_array($headerClasses) ? implode(' ', $headerClasses) : $headerClasses; ?>`